# User pool does not exist: AWS adminConfirmSignUp

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-cognito

For some reason, only the adminConfirmSignUp gives this error. Authentication using CognitoUser doesn't give this error. Both of them are configured to the same user pool and region.

Below is the code for authentication using cognitoUser, which is working:

```js
public async login(req: UserLoginRequest): Promise<object> {
        return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`This is the req password-----> ${req.password}`)
            try {
                var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails({
                    Username: req.emailAddress,
                    Password: req.password
                });
                var userData = {
                    Username: req.emailAddress,
                    Pool: this.userPool
                };
                this.cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
                await this.authenticateUser(this.cognitoUser, authenticationDetails).then(value=> {
                    resolve(value)
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(`This is the login error catch----> ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`I entered into catch .......${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }
  
    private async authenticateUser(cognitoUser: AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser, authenticationDetails: AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails) {
        console.log(`Inside authenticate user`);
        console.log(`This is the cognitoUser -----> ${JSON.stringify(cognitoUser)} and these are the authentication details-----> ${JSON.stringify(authenticationDetails)}`)
        try{
        return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
                await cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
                    onSuccess: (result) => {
                        console.log(`This is the success result ----> ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
                        resolve(result)
                    },
                    onFailure: (error) => {
                        console.log(`This is the error being returned in onFailure ----> ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
                        resolve(error)
                    }
                })
        })
    }
    catch(error){
        rejects(error);
    }
    }
```

The confirm user, which uses AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider doesn't work. Gives out an error user pool doesn't exist:

```js
private async confirmUser(resetDetails: ResetPassword, cognitoAdmin: AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider) {
        console.log(`This is the admin config cognito ----> ${JSON.stringify(cognitoAdmin)}`)
        return new Promise<any>(async (resolve,reject)=>{
            console.log(`Inside confirm`);
            const confirmParams = {
                UserPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID!,
                Username: resetDetails.emailAddress!
            }
            console.log(`This is the user pool ID -----> ${confirmParams.UserPoolId} and this is the region----> ${cognitoAdmin.config.region}`);
            await cognitoAdmin.adminConfirmSignUp(confirmParams, async (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`This is the admin user confirm error ---> ${err}`)
                    reject(err);
                }
                else {
                    cognitoAdmin.adminUpdateUserAttributes({
                        UserAttributes: [{
                            Name: 'email_verified',
                            Value: 'true'
                        }],
                        UserPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID!,
                        Username: resetDetails.emailAddress!
                    }, (err, data) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err)
                        }
                        else {
                            resolve(data)
                        }
                    }
                    )
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

This is the cognitoAdmin argument details sent to the  `cognitoAdmin` parameter of the above confirmUser method:

```
var cognitoAdmin = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ region: process.env.COGNITO_POOL_REGION!});
```

Comment: It might be nothing but there is an exclamation mark at the end of this line: `UserPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID!`. You sure this is how it suppose to be?

Comment: Hi @AleksanderWons, That is alright. Its just a non-nullable condition in typescript.

Comment: Could you maybe attach the actual payloads being send in both cases? Maybe then it would be easier to identify where the issue is.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Nope its been 3 months. Not yet. weirdly, it worked the next day without me making any changes. But now I have done a similar implementation on another application, and I am facing the same issue.

Comment: One guess: it might need the `region` to be set too. I hit something similar while using the AWS CLI, where specifying a user pool ID without a region failed (even though the region name is embedded in the user pool ID. ‍♂️